AWS CDK: How do I create an NsRecord only if it doesn't exist?
In my AWS CDK stack, I have the following, which creates a HostedZone and then associates that zone to an NsRecord as follows:
const zone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, 'MyHostedZone', {
    zoneName: myCustomZone
});

new route53.NsRecord(this, 'MyServiceNsRecord', {
    zone: zone,
    values: zone.hostedZoneNameServers || []
});

The problem is that if I re-run my build/release pipeline (say, after I've made other changes to the app), I get the following error:
Tried to create resource record set [name='my.domain.name.', type='NS'] but it already exists
Is there a way for me to configure the HostedZone and/or NsRecord constructor so that it performs an "upsert" - i.e. creates the record only if it doesn't exist, otherwise updates it?  Or if I cannot do an upsert, simply does nothing?
(I realize that the NsRecordProps interface has a deleteExisting flag, but I understand this can be dangerous to use.  I would like to avoid that.)

What do you want to achieve with this code? A PublicHostedZone already has NS records with the values of zoneHostedZoneNameServers out of the box, and your code seems to be trying to create a duplicate set of records.

@gshpychka so I should remove values: zone.hostedZoneNameServers || [] from my NsRecord constructor?

You should remove the NsRecord instance altogether.

Thanks @gshpychka - that worked!  I have marked this as the answer.

Thanks to @gshpychka for showing me the answer.  I simply needed to remove the code that constructs the NsRecord.

This does not answer the question as stated, though (how to create a record only if it doesn't exist). The short answer to the original question is "you can't and shouldn't do this", and the long answer is that it's possible, but you really shouldn't do this
